# Open Folders since Jquery from CSS Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script on CSS that allows you to simulate a file explorer on HTML.

The problem that I have is that I want to create a button that automatically opens all the folders and subfolders in that list.

Here is an example of the css that is being called when a checkbox is clicked:

```
li input:checked + ol
{
    background: url('http://www.01800iglesia.org/imagenes/numeros-01.png') 44px 5px no-repeat;
    background-size: 12px 12px;
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -44px; /* 20px */
    padding: 1.563em 0 0 80px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
li input:checked + ol > li { display: block; margin: 0 0 0.125em; }
li input:checked + ol > li:last-child { margin: 0 0 0.063em; }
```

Live example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qzojy5ko/3/

Is there any way to get the folders open since the click of a button?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The JSFiddle you provided doesn't seem to be working, but it looks like you essentially trying to check/uncheck all checkboxes, so it might be worth checking this out: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/14966733/check-all-uncheck-all-checkboxes-js

Comment: You're right, the fiddle wasnt working. I put a new working fiddle now. Regarding your answer its a bit more complicated that just checking the boxes. Please see the fiddle so you can have a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked and updated your fiddle with a working solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/xgz0z54k/3/

You can use the `.prop()` to set the value of the checkbox on the click event.

```
jQuery("#my_button").click(function() {
  $("input").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I needed. I had tried was with $('#my_id').attr('checked') and it didn't work. Now I see that with the prop it works pefectly. Thank you very much once again!

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you're essentially checking and unchecking checkboxes:

```
$(function() {

    var folder = $('.folder').next('input');

    $('#my_button').click(function() {
        if (folder.filter(':checked').length == folder.length) {
            folder.prop('checked', false);
            $(this).val('Open Folders');
        } else {
            folder.prop('checked', true);
            $(this).val('Close Folders');
        }
    });

    folder.change(function() {
        if (folder.filter(':checked').length == folder.length) {
            $('#my_button').val('Close Folders');
        } else {
            $('#my_button').val('Open Folders');
        }
    });

});
```

Ideally, instead of `$('.folder').next('input')`, you'll want to add a class to the checkboxes themselves, and change that to `$('input-class')`.